# Angular + Clarity: Icons are not loaded properly

Tags: angular, svg, vmware-clarity, webui

So i'm building a little web app with the help of clarity. Im using the build in icons for a side menue among other things. Now, the first icon i put in is fine, shows up no problem. Then when i put in more, they were just showing the fallback animation as if the icons are not found.
I've tried to dig a little into it, apparently there's some icons in their library that consistently work for me and others that constantly don't. I couldn't find any correlation to set/package, version or anything else. I use multiple of these icons in the same block, if it works or not solely depends on the shape property i specify, which is consistent no matter where i put it.

I've looked into the actual directory in my workspace and the files are all there for each icon including the svg mapping path. I couldn't find any significant difference between the files either.

I'm starting to get desperate, does anyone have an idea as to what might be going on?

Thanks in advance.

(P. S. unfortunately i can't show any of the actual code due to company guidelines)

Comment: I have converted all 1100 Clarity Icons (and 6300 from other Icon Sets) to a ``<svg-icon>`` native Web Component, to create the icons client-side. It will load only the icons you use. See: https://iconmeister.github.io

Comment: Have you followed the steps here to ensure the icons are loaded? By default some are loaded but not all. https://angular.clarity.design/icons/get-started

Comment: @JeremyWilken  i haven't taken any extra steps to load them but the files ARE there